# How to play MP3 from PPHP If Else

Tags: javascript, php, mp3

```
<button onclick="playSound()">Play</button>
<script>
function playSound() {
    let src = '../../sounds/paSound.mp3';
    let audio = new Audio(src);
    audio.play();
}
</script>
```

I have the code above that plays the mp3 sound when clicking the Play button.

What I want to do is to call and play the sound from an if else statement in PHP. Is there a way to do that?

```
if(statement==true){
 //call playSound js function
}
```

I have tried the below code:
[image]

Comment: Do u mean like this? 
<?php if (): ?>
<button onclick="playSound()">Play</button>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: I think this code will still be needed to be triggered by a click on the button. What i need is an automatic call to the function playSound in case if statement is satisfied

Comment: Do you need it real time? or this can wait for the next page load, where you will `playSound()` on page load?

Comment: it can probably wait for the next page load and play the sound.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to pass data to JS and then do if/else.

```
<script>
var jsvar = <?php print $phpvar ;?>
if (jsvar == x) 
play music
</script>
```

or

```
<?php if (): ?>

<script>

    let src = '../../sounds/paSound.mp3';
    let audio = new Audio(src);
    audio.play();

</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: or on `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    playSound()
)});`